# Tensor assignation in Tensorflow 1.2.1 (decorators?)

Tags: tensorflow, decorator, tensor

I am triying to work on a neural network where part of the neurons are related by an explicit parametric equation.

I have tried with the code:

```
for i in range(npxx-1):
    for j in range(npxy-1):
        F[:,i,j,0] = a0_tf*U[:,i,j,0] + b0_tf*U[:,i,j,1]
        F[:,i,j,1] = a1_tf*U[:,i,j,1] + b1_tf*U[:,i,j,2]
        F[:,i,j,2] = a2_tf*U[:,i,j,2] + b2_tf*U[:,i,j,0]
```

But obviously it doesn't work as tensor assignement is not allowed under TensorFlow framework. What is the most straightforward way to do so? I have tried by defining a function and using the decorator `@tf.funcion` but this is not available in Tensorflow 1.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.roll`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random.uniform([2, 2, 2, 3])
a = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
b = 1 - a
rolled_x = tf.roll(x, -1, axis=-1)
output = x * tf.reshape(a, [1, 1, 1, 3]) + rolled_x * tf.reshape(b, [1, 1, 1, 3])
```